# Maximum RAM on Biostar P4M8PM7 Socket775 mATX board

Tags: memory, hardware, via

I have a server with a Biostar P4M8PM7 ("Pro-M7") board based on a VIA chipset.  It's a strange board to put in a server because it seems like more of a desktop board to me, but alas!

It takes DDR2-667 (PC5300) RAM.  What I can't figure out is the maximum amount I can put in it, as I cannot find the manual anywhere online.  I've found a few marketing broadsheets from online retailers that say, "up to 2 GB of RAM!" but I am not sure whether to believe them.  They also do not seem to be quite for the same board, as they indicate DDR2 400/533 RAM, for example:  http://www.geeks.com/details.asp?invtid=P4M8P-M7.  The manufacturer's web site says the same thing, but does not elaborate.

It's a 64-bit CPU and board;  is there a technical reason why the board would not be able to address more than 2 GB?  Can someone tell me what sort of that reason that would be?  I bought this server from someone really hoping I could put 8 to 16 in it, and wanted to do some research before I gave up.

On a related note, it's not indicated anywhere whether it can take ECC RAM;  the existing chips are not ECC, but most memory sold in the range I'm looking for (e.g. DIMMs with enough chip density to do 8 GB) seems to be server-class and for that reason ECC.  Any ideas?

Thank you very much for your consideration in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It only has two memory slots and uses a VIA P4M800 Pro chipset which can only handle 2GB (i.e. 2 x 1GB modules). It can't utilise ECC.